# In Pandas, is there a means to succinctly compare multiple columns to the value of a single column per row without resorting to loops?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In Pandas, how does one compare multiple columns to the value of a single column without looping over the entire `DataFrame`? Preferably, the solution would work for a variable (dynamic) number of 'multiple columns'.

For example, consider the `DataFrame` below where the number of V# columns is variable:

```
Idx |  A  |  V0 |  V1...
----------------------
 0  |  1  |  2  |  0
 1  |  2  |  4  |  3
 2  |  6  |  4  |  5
 3  |  2  |  3  |  5
```

Since the number of V# columns is variable, I'd like the ability to construct a list of column names to pass to the the appropriate Pandas function.

```py
v_columns = [f'V{i}' for i in range(0, 2)]  # Output is ['V0' 'V1']
```

I'm hoping for a succinct solution such as the following erroneous code:

```py
bool_mask = df[v_columns] > df['A']  # This doesn't work as intended.
```

Of course, the above code adds a column for each row in the `DataFrame` whereas I'm looking for something like the following:

```
     0  |  True   |  True
     1  |  False  |  True
     2  |  True   |  False
     3  |  False  |  False
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is `.gt`:

```
# axis='rows' also works
df[v_columns].gt(df['A'], axis=0)
```

Another option is to use numpy broadcasting, which might be a bit less readable:

```
df[v_columns] > df['A'].to_numpy()[:,None]
```

Output:

```
      V0     V1
0   True  False
1   True   True
2  False  False
3   True   True
```